# Riemann Zeta function in C for negative's odd reals

Tags: c, function, math, gcc, discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to code the Riemann Zeta function in C but I'm having quite issues with the negative odds one. Since Even negatives are 0 by definition. Only for Real numbers the function, not complex. So 0..1 it's **undefined**. I know it's some math error I'm doing, but I started today to read about this function and I'm trying to learn.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double zeta(double s, long long int n)
{
    double p=0.0;
    if(s<0 && fmod(s,2)==0)
    {
        return p;
    }
    if(s==0) { return -0.5;}
    if(s>0 && s<=1)
    {
        puts("Undefined. ");
        exit(-1);
    }
    long long int i;
    for(i=n; i>0; i--)
    {

        p+=pow(i,-s);
    }
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    double s;
    puts("Enter real number to Zeta function: ");
    scanf("%lf",&s);
    printf("\n%.15lf",zeta(s,1000000));
    return 0;

}
```

It's just a sketch... Nothing professional here!

example: zeta(-5) = -0.003968253968253
it's giving 1.036927755143338...

I'm only having issues with **NEGATIVE REAL** ones...
I'm on Windows 10, Codeblocks with GCC.

The code was update with the @NPE contributions but still not working for negative real odds...

Comment: The Riemann zeta function is defined as sum(1/n^s for 1 ≤ n < ∞) when the real part of s is greater than 1. You are summing n^s (`pow(i,s)`) rather than 1/n^s (`pow(i,-s)` or `1/pow(i,s)`). 1.0369… is zeta(5). The sum will not converge for negative s. Instead, the function is defined as an analytic continuation and must be computed differently.

Comment: Looks like you're computing zeta(abs(x))...

Comment: To add some details to @EricPostpischil comment (shouldn't it be an answer instead?) The formula for negative integers is `S(-n) = (-1)^n * (B_{n+1})/(n + 1)` where `B_n` is the n-th Bernoulli number.

Comment: I'm not using abs()! What can I do for negative ones?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi: It would be an answer if I were positive, but I never really deal with the zeta function and was just going by stuff I looked up. So I hedged with a comment. Feel free to enter an answering, using my text and information or your own.

Answer (score 2):

I did not participate in comments, sorry.

following the definition of the zeta-function the simple way of coding is (I just changed s to -s from your code, and added the 'level of convergence n' as a parameter)

```
double zeta_simple(double s, long long int n)
{
    double p=0.0;
    long long int i;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {

        p+=pow(i,-s);
    }
    return p;
}
```

However the problem is that you start adding the "big" numbers before the "small" and soon you will hit underflow operation. So what you want to do is

```
double zeta(double s, long long int n)
{
    double p=0.0;
    long long int i;
    for(i=n; i>0; i--)
    {

        p+=pow(i,-s);
    }
    return p;
}
```

you can test convergence with s=2 which converges to PI^2/6.0 and s=4 which converges to PI^4/90.0

```
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679L
int main()
{
      long long int n;
      for (long long int n=10; n<=100000000; n*=10)
      {
        printf("%28.16f\t %28.16f\n", zeta(4.0, n), zeta2(4.0, n));
      }
      printf("%s=%20.16f\n\n","PI^4/90", PI*PI*PI*PI/90.0);

      for (long long int n=10; n<=10000000000; n*=10)
      {
        printf("%28.16f\t %28.16f\n", zeta(2.0, n), zeta2(2.0, n));
      }
      printf("%s=%20.16f\n","PI^2/6 ", PI*PI/6.0);
}
```

you get

```
          1.0820365834937564               1.0820365834937566
          1.0823229053444732               1.0823229053444725
          1.0823232333783044               1.0823232333783073
          1.0823232337108049               1.0823232337108359
          1.0823232337111379               1.0823232337109849
          1.0823232337111381               1.0823232337109849
          1.0823232337111381               1.0823232337109849
          1.0823232337111381               1.0823232337109849
PI^4/90=  1.0823232337111379

          1.5497677311665408               1.5497677311665408
          1.6349839001848929               1.6349839001848925
          1.6439345666815597               1.6439345666815606
          1.6448340718480596               1.6448340718480665
          1.6449240668982261               1.6449240668982523
          1.6449330668487265               1.6449330668487985
          1.6449339668482315               1.6449339668477756
          1.6449340568482265               1.6449340573291047
          1.6449340658482263               1.6449340600880324
          1.6449340667482264               1.6449340600880324
PI^2/6 =  1.6449340668482264
```

see how the convergence of `zeta_simple` stops after a while... For convergence to continue you have to use `zeta`

You can also see that for 10000000000 operations (hence the use of long long int) you only get a precision on 9 digits for s=2. And as s increase so does the rate of convergence.

Therefore for small s to be efficient people use accelerated convergence formulae.

If you want to dig further I recommend you look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183680/modern-formula-for-calculating-riemann-zeta-function

Also wat is really interesting is when you start poking around with `s` complex

Comment: Even with your zeta() I still having wrong answers to negative odds one... 

zeta(-5,1000) = 167167083333250020.000000000000000

the correct is -0.00396825396825396825

Comment: zeta function with s a real converges only when s>1.0 otherwise it goes to infinity. To get the result you are looking for you need a totally other approach.  You must consider s a complex and as @EricPostpischil said "the function is defined as an analytic continuation and must be computed differently". For that you can have look at the thesis cited in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183680/modern-formula-for-calculating-riemann-zeta-function

Comment: And before you ask. even if you adjust the above code making s complex it wont work and you are back looking at the thesis. But it is a good exercice and kind of mind blowing...

Comment: On a more fun level you can watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=10&v=w-I6XTVZXww

Comment: How to compute differently? I can test if it is negative and apllied the correct for of computation... If I know how to do it. I'm using the Euler-Maclaurin Summation yet on my algorithm...

Comment: I think this article gives you the limitation of Euler-Maclaurin Summation http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Miscellaneous/zetaevaluations.pdf However if you want you can edit your post with your implementation of Euler-Maclaurin. And we will see if something is off (well it that case it should belong to code review maybe, I don't know)

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, I'm just a newbie trying to program... This equations sounds like greek *tu dum tss* to me... I need some help with the translation of the equations. My function calculates (n!=1)>infinite on the real plane with a very good approximation, all checked on Wolfram Alpha, it's perfect the approximation... But I just can't understend the math of the negatives, I need some clues in human language... Also works on negative evens... But the Odds... It's making me sick